# Cupy what's the difference between `pip install cupy` and `pip install cupy-cuda115`

Tags: cupy

as stated in the title, what's the difference between the two install methods?

If I want to publish a package, what should I write in the `setup.cfg` file? i.e.

```
[options]
...
install_requires =
    cupy or cupy-cuda1xx
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `pip install cupy` builds from source (sdist)
- `pip install cupy-cudaXY` installs the prebuilt wheel for CUDA X.Y

> If I want to publish a package, what should I write in the `setup.cfg` file?

Unfortunately there is no perfect solution yet but we are getting there. Currently there is an experimental metapackage on PyPI.org called `cupy-wheel` for downstream to depend on. What it does is it detects the installing environment and chooses the correct wheel to install. It'd become official starting CuPy v11. See https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/6688.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that sounds great! BTW, when are you guys going to publish cupy v11?

Comment: This summer. See the release schedule here: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/6246